# Controlling randomness of distribution in Geometry nodes on a grid

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to interpolate between poison disk random and a grid in geometry nodes(using point distribute and instance on a "grid" mesh? I would prefer a solution using Poisson disk to minimize intersection of instanced meshes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign random material to whole object using Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227082/assign-random-material-to-whole-object-using-geometry-nodes)

Comment: No, but thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to explain more about you final goal, your description is not really clear, add some images and so. This is what i understood " instances distribude in a grid mesh with the option of changing the random seed" if that is the case, the above comment is the that

Comment: Do i understand your goal ? you want the same effect as the "randomness" slider in the Voronoi node of the shader editor, right ? Value of 0 means perfectly aligned grid, value of 1 means points are displaced while respecting a minimal relative distance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the exact behaviour you're looking for doesn't exist yet. you could theoretically interpolate between the positions in a grid and the positions based on a Poisson distribution. But it wouldn't work since the instance ids wouldn't match and there is no way to instance a specific amount of points. ([Point Distribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_distribute.html) node only takes a density input) So the modifier would maybe work in a specific situation, but you would have to tweak all the properties again for the slightest variation in geometry.

You can approximate it with an [Attribute Mix](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_mix.html) node to interpolate between the grid points locations and a random offset using an [Attribute Randomize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_randomize.html) node.

[image]

Result :

[image]

I don't know how difficult the implementation of a voronoi displacement would be, but one could tweak the modifier to get the kind of result that we get in the shader node editor.

[image]

Comment: Since the root of Voronoi is a random-per-cell feature point, you've already done it, haven't you? Your monkeys _are_ at Voronoi distance=0? The impossible bit would be evaluating shortest-distance-to-feature-point for every point on the surface.  No data-structure to contain that, unlesss you sample a texture.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yeah you're right ^^ Figured the algorithm would be more complicated ! As you mentioned I guess the tricky part is to figure out the N sphere radius between each point and its neighbors